# How to include external files in laravel project?

Tags: laravel

So I have a public directory in my localhost that contains some classes that I want to be able to use in my current laravel project.

So how will I include these, external classes/files in laravel?

I tried to add these files in my composer.json file,

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "../public_classes/priceClass.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "../public_classes/priceClass.php"
        ]
    },
```

and do `composer dump-autoload`, then when I tried to call the function, it won't work.

Comment: Which kind of files you want to include? Classes (with namespaces) or simple functions?

Comment: I wanted to include oop classes, but I end up doing simple functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing was I put the path to file in my composer.json, then do `composer dump-autoload`.

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "../public_classes/priceClass.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "../public_classes/priceClass.php"
        ]
    },
```

then, the file I wanted to add, I edit it into simple functions instead of oop ones.

priceClass.php:

```
<?php

function getPrices(){
/* 
*
*
*Statements here 
*
*/
}

?>
```

And call it in my laravel controller simply by

```
$prices = getPrices();
```

I did this, because when I tried to have something like:

```
class Prices(){

    public function getPrices(){ 
         ....
    }

}
```

then call it in my laravel controller:

```
$priceClass = new Prices();
$prices = $priceClass->getPrices();
```

I ended up having an error, something like: Prices class not found.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add anything in `composer.json` if you're using [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). For example, you can create PHP file in `\app\MyClasses\MyClass.php` and use this namespace in custom class: `namespace App\MyClasses`.

Laravel will autoload this class for you.

Comment: the files i'm trying to include does not belong in the same directory as the laravel project. the files are in a separate directory. they are my repository classes.

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to include a few classes in my Laravel Project for that I just copied the files in a new directory(app/Libraries) and assigned Package name to all the classes and followed [PSR-4 Autoloading standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for all those class files and I have added following code in my `composer.json`.

```
     ...
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "app/Libraries",
            ],
...
```

hope this will solve your problem...

Happy to help!!!